# Display Port No Signal for HP & MSI Optix MPG27CQ

Tags: windows-10, external-display, displayport, auto-detect

The computer I currently have is as follows:

```
Hewlett-Packard 3646h version 786G7 v01.14, 
Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU,
Package: Socket 775 LGA,
4GB DDR3 Generic Ram (4 x 1Gb Sticks),
240Gb Hyper X Savage SSD,
Generic Old Style Square Pnp Monitor Connected through VGA.
```

*[Hewlett-Packard 3646h](https://d1ebmxcfh8bf9c.cloudfront.net/u44068/image_id_874197.jpg) :: Image*

*[Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 CPU](https://intel.ly/2Vs7rVv) :Specs & info Page.*

I am trying to Set up the new monitor that I have just brought which is 
An

*[MSI Optix MPG27CQ](https://www.msi.com/Monitor/Optix-MPG27CQ)*,

The motherboard that I have  does not have a HDMI input or output,
 so I have had to connect it using the provided Display Port Cable.
When trying to Auto Detect the monitor in windows It is Not detecting anything,
& on switching the monitor on it just say No DP input. *Stays on for around 10/15 seconds then switches itself off.*
I have updated all drivers via intel, none of which were for the display or gpu. I have switched off the system & monitor and restarted both after installing the updated drivers to try again.
Still not connecting.

In windows 10 home control panel (Which I loath! they have removed alot of options and functionality)
Display settings is not even an option.
I have set up The old version of control panel 
from windows 7 but still display setting are not shown.
Have tried bottom right icon - connect but still not detecting anything.
Can Anyone help? I have searched forums and Youtube
but all the information is very basic stuff I have already tried.
Looked in BIOS, nothing there either for display.
Do I need to install anything from MSI?
there was no disk in the box, so I'm assuming this is not the issue..

*I have just noticed in the driver details for my old monitor there is a file called monitor.inf when searching my hard-drive for this file multiple folders have come up containing monitor.inf some of which are AMD folders and a few have names with dual monitor in them can I change settings in any of these to detect my new monitor?*
Viewing the monitor.inf file using: *[Sublime Text editor 3](https://www.sublimetext.com)* 
shows a list of manufacturers in order, 
I have done a search and MSI is not present on this list anywhere.
Not sure if this information helps but its interesting. Can I manually add the code to instal this Monitor?

I have found this Article:[Manually Edit monitor.inf file](https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/367273/fixed-33-i-manually-edited-my-nv_disp-inf-and-refresh-rate-fixed-and-new-lcd-added-33-/) about manually adding your monitor to the disp.inf & monitor.inf Files Which seems quite useful. Still not exactly sure what code to add but I'm working on it.

Have just looked at the AMD auto Detect drivers page here:

[AMD Auto Detect](https://www.amd.com/en/support)

& it looks like it only works for AMD Radeon Graphics Cards or Dedicated AMD not Intel Chipsets with AMD Components.

```
    Update
    I have fiddled around with the cables and plugged all available    
    cables in including the HDMI cable into the monitor aswell as the   
    provided USB cable, HDMI Is connected to the monitor but not to my
    PC, windows has detected it as a monitor but it is just displaying
    a black screen. I tried to Extend my screen onto the new monitor but            
    that did not work, I then set the MSI Monitor as my main screen & now  
    cannot change it back. Which file would this information be stored    
    in? If both monitors are plugged in then the MSI one becomes my main
    screen, Stay's black & I cannot move my mouse onto the smaller 
    screen to play with the new setting available. Im Stuck Again.
```

Comment: Hard to believe an old computer, going by the CPU, has a DP connection. Are you using an adapter then? Which one? And what about the graphics card? Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia It does have a DP Port & no I haven't used any adapters yet but I have ordered a VGA to hdmi adapter to see if this will solve the problem. I was just wondering if the built in graphics card was strong enough to power such a monitor as it does not have a seperate or very strong gpu... Ordered Vga to hmdi and an adapter hopefully these help.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia the two adapters i have brought are:                                  HDMI Female To VGA Male Converter Adapter 1080P                                   HDMI Male to VGA Male Adapter Cable.                                               Hopeing one of them works

Comment: An integrated graphics cards of that time and age cannot have DP, that came much later. Please post your exact graphics card and/or the PC's model.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Graphics card viewed by CPU-z is:             Intel(R) Q45/Q43 Express Chipset (Microsoft Corporation) There is no other information being show. But the motherboard and PC case definately have a DP Port, Has a DP Symbol And looks a rectangle with a corner cut off. Similar connector inside to a hardrive and the DP Cable that came with the monitor fits in there perfectly.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Found some more information about the graphics card in the settings, extra bit is: (WDDM 1.1)

Comment: The chioset supports HDMI/DP  after all (the CPU misled me) but up to only 2 monitors total.. So, either you need to change somerhing in BIOS or install Intel drivrers os both...